# Django Error----name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, cart, self

I am trying to add products to my cart along with foreignkey User who would be the current user in session. I know usually you can do self.request.user, but in this case adding self.request.user is not working. I have also tried running it with self as one of the parameter.

For example:

```
def cart(request, self, product_id):
```

I have also tested without using:

```
curr_user = get_object_or_404(User,user=self.request.user)
```

and instead:

```
owned_by=self.request.user
```

or

```
owned_by=request.user
```

for adding to Cart and also all_posts but neither worked.

I get the error with the code screenshots below:

```
NameError at /mycart/6
name 'self' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/mycart/6
Django Version: 2.1.3
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value: name 'self' is not defined
Exception Location: mysrc/cart/views.py in cart, line 25
Python Executable:  env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.0
Python Path:
```

views.py

```
#Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Cart
from shop.models import Products

@login_required
def cart(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Products,id=product_id)

    curr_user = get_object_or_404(User,user=self.request.user)


    cart = Cart(item=product, quantity=1, price=product.price, owned_by=curr_user)
    cart.save()

    all_posts = Cart.objects.filter(owned_by=curr_user)
    context = {'all_posts':all_posts}

    return render(request,'cart/mycart.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from shop.models import Products
from users.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

class Cart(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default = 0)

    owned_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default= False)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.cart, name='cart-cart'),
    path('mycart/<product_id>', views.cart, name ='cart-cart'),
]
```

template file:

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h3>Search Result</h3>

{% for post in posted %}
    <article class="media content-section">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <small><a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'profile' %}">{{ post.seller }}</a></small>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
        </div>
        <h3><a class="article-title">{{ post.book_name }} <span style="font-size:14px;">by {{post.author}}</span></a></h3>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.course }} | {{ post.dept_id }}</p>
        <p class="article-content"><b>${{ post.price }}</b></p>
        <div class="media">
    <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ shop.book_img.image.url }}">
  </div>
          <form action="{% url 'cart-cart' product_id=post.pk %}" method="post">



            <p>Unique Item ID: {{ post.pk }}</p>
          <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{% url 'cart-cart' product_id=post.pk%}">add to cart</a>

        </form>


      </div>
    </article>

{% endfor %} {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: In the function cart you are trying to do `self.request`. self represents the instance of the class. Is the function defined in a class.? Otherwise your code is wrong

Comment: You have `def cart(request, product_id)` which does not have `self` and you are using `self.request.user`.

Answer (score 0):

The `cart` is a method within a class, the first parameter needs to be `self` which is the instance of that class.

Change the signature of `cart` to `def cart(self, request, product_id)` and it should work.